# Convert time format "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" to "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSz"

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am very much new to scala. How to convert date format?

The original string is: `14/5/2020 12:57:09`
I need to convert to: `2020-5-14T12:57:09.000z`

Comment: are you using python or scala?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [to_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp.html) , info around why `timePolicy = LEGACY` is used - [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html)

#### Data Preparation

```
sql.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame([
                                    ("14/5/2020 12:57:09",)
                                    ,("16/12/2020 05:57:09",)
                                    ,("28/2/2020 22:45:10",)
                               ]
                               , ['timestamp_str'])

sparkDF.show()

+-------------------+
|      timestamp_str|
+-------------------+
| 14/5/2020 12:57:09|
|16/12/2020 05:57:09|
| 28/2/2020 22:45:10|
+-------------------+

root
 |-- timestamp_str: string (nullable = true)
```

#### Conversion

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|      timestamp_str|     timestamp_date|
+-------------------+-------------------+
| 14/5/2020 12:57:09|2020-05-14 12:57:09|
|16/12/2020 05:57:09|2020-12-16 05:57:09|
| 28/2/2020 22:45:10|2020-02-28 22:45:10|
+-------------------+-------------------+

root
 |-- timestamp_str: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp_date: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Seq("14/5/2020 12:57:09").toDF("time_str")
.withColumn(
  "time_formatted", 
  date_format(
    to_timestamp('time_str, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"), 
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'z'")
).show(false)

+------------------+------------------------+
|time_str          |time_formatted          |
+------------------+------------------------+
|14/5/2020 12:57:09|2020-05-14T12:57:09.000z|
+------------------+------------------------+
```